# IIf to assign variable values inside the IIf

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to understand why I can't use the IIf in this way to assign a value to a variable.

```
dim i as integer
dim j as integer

i = 1
j = 2

if i = 1 or iif(j = i, j = 10, j = 20) then
    msgbox j
end if
```

I know that I can use the IIf to assign a variable like this:

```
j = IIf(1 = 2, 5, 10)
```

j will equal 10 in that instance.

Comment: IIf just doesn't work this way, nor is intended to. Study the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dda-DK%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1012957)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396).

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be this:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Dim j As Integer
j = 2

Select Case i
    Case 1
        'Do nothing
    Case j
        j = 10
    Case Else
        j = 20
End Select

MsgBox j
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative workaround would be

```
dim i as integer
dim j as integer

i = 1
j = 2

if j = i then
    j = 10
else
    j= iif(j = i, 10, 20)
end if
```

You cannot really use and iif statment as part of an if statement (you cannnt mix them in the same statement).